# Confusion around the not-small breakpoint in tachyons

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, tachyons-css

Using [tachyons](http://tachyons.io/) css library:

I don't understand how the `ns` breakpoint works. According to the docs the breakpoints are defined as:

```
Media Query Extensions:
  -ns = not-small [ @media screen and (min-width: 30em) ]
  -m  = medium [ @media screen and (min-width: 30em) and (max-width: 60em) ]
  -l  = large [ @media screen and (min-width: 60em) ]
```

Thought the following code will ensure only a single div's visibility depending on the width.

```
<div class="dn-ns dn-m dn-l">Mobile</div>
<div class="dn db-ns">Small</div>
<div class="dn db-m">Medium</div>
<div class="dn db-l">Large</div>
```

However, the `ns` breakpoint also appears to kicks in at `medium` and `large` breakpoints.

[mobile breakpoint, it's default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GStC0.png)

[ns and medium, both kicking in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGttG.png)

[ns and large, both visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvkfn.png)

Is it because the `ns` breakpoint does not specify an upper bound and so covers anything not mobile?

Comment: Yes, anything with  width 30em or above will do the settings in the ns media query.  It’s simply saying not small.

Answer (score 1):

ns breakpoint means the class will apply to all the sizes which are not small that (min-width:30em // only mobile devices will have width below 30em, so ns will work on tablet, desktop, large display device widths)

```
<!---display: none on all devices which are not small(dn-m and dn-l are redundant here) --->
<div class="dn-ns dn-m dn-l">Mobile</div>
```